# books in which post-human has become a discorporate distributed artifact

Tags: story-identification, transhuman

20 or maybe 30 years ago I read two books by a pair of authors which I would like to identify. They didn't strike me as remarkable at the time but in retrospect they were very imaginative even if they weren't memorable. It's a long time ago so I'm going to be unfortunately vague and I may even be conflating more than book.

The first book involved a hierarchy of space-travellers and they are somehow involved in a vortex visiting Earth. Mankind enters the vortex in spaceships but they interact with beings at the bottom of the hierarchy. Near the end of the book there is mention of a separate inverted spiral but I can't remember anything more than that.

I can be more specific about the other book because it had a visit by humans to a post-human who had become a nebulous solar-system sized intelligence. I remember that they asked a question of this being and he replied but warned that he had only partially arrived at the communication point so he may change his answer when more of him was assembled.

A snippet comes to mind in which someone says of a post-human that he had become distributed as an asteroidal ring but I think that this is a different book.

There is a good example of a distributed intelligence in "**House of Suns**" by *Alastair Reynolds* but this isn't the book (and neither is "**The Black Cloud** by *Fred Hoyle*).

Comment: On the other hand, if you think these are two books in a series, say as much, and it's valid again.

Comment: I believe that they are unrelated and by the same authors and thought they would be easier to pin down if this information were available. I think the information about the post-human is more specific so I could totally remove the bit about the other book (the vortex) if you think that would help in some way.